# How to resolve this error not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: android, xml, emulation

Here is my code it shows the following error

> Line 6 is giving this error , not well-formed (invalid token). How to solve this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    
android:layout_width="match_parent"
    
android:layout_height="match_parent"
    
android:background="@color/greenColor"
    
I have added comment here in <!--  -->
    
tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

Comment: you can't add comment inside a tag body.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the comments when you have closed the tag
i.e

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/greenColor"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<!--This is comment-->
```